# Trying to redirect PHP shopping cart once empty

Tags: php, url, uri, shopping-cart

I've created a PHP shopping cart, it's just the redirects that don't work. So when I add an item, it shows a blank page, but if you go to the cart, the item is there. This is how I'm storing the url:

```
    <?php
       $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
       $current_url = substr($current_url, 1);

        $results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM apps A INNER JOIN device D ON D.DeviceID = A.DeviceID WHERE D.DeviceName = '$os'");
            if ($results) { 
            //output results from database
            while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
            {

                echo "<div class=\"col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4\">";
                echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
                echo '<h2>'.$obj->ApplicationName.'</h2>';
                echo '<p>'.$obj->ApplicationDescription.'</p>';
                echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->ApplicationID.'" />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
                echo '</form></div>';
             }

            }
     ?>
```

And this is the code that should redirect it back once the cart is empty

```
    <?php
    session_start(); //start session
    include_once("includes/connect.php"); //include config file

    //empty cart by distroying current session
    if(isset($_GET["emptycart"]) && $_GET["emptycart"]==1)
    {
        $return_url = $_GET["return_url"]; //return url
        session_destroy();
        header('Location:'.$return_url);
    }
```

Comment: why are you adding apostrophes in the URL field?  if this isn't the issue, open your browser inspector and check if a response is even sent back with a URL

Answer (score 0):

Header location must contain space like this

```
 header('Location: '.$return_url);exit();
```